# how to overwrite css property min-height or height

Tags: css

How can I override the min-height property in the code below? I am trying to set it with `min-height:none;` but its not working. I just want to remove this property.

```
/* original class */
.navbar {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

/* override class */
.navbar {
  min-height: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)'s initial value is `0`:

```
.navbar {
   min-height: 0;
}
```

In CSS3, you can also use [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) or [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) keywords:

```
.navbar {
   min-height: initial; /* or `unset` */
}
```

Comment: height: `height: auto;`